# How to run the PHP code written within namespace?

Tags: php

I want to run the code from the [PHP official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php).  The code is:

```
<?php
namespace foo {
    class bar {
    }

    echo bar::class; // foo\bar
}
?>
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script
```

I don't know the reason.

Comment: Works just fine for me: https://3v4l.org/3fNGG

Comment: But I running from my command prompt in Linux.

Comment: Is it because my character encoding is UTF-8?

Comment: My guess would be that there’s something at the top of the file, either white space or a BOM maybe

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was an empty line above. When removed, it works fine.  I need to know more about BOM.

Comment: [BOMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) are/were more common on Windows, and I’m not sure if you’ll run across them if you are Linux-only

Comment: No. Even though my character encoding is UTF 8 (both in Emacs and Termial), I never had an issue with BOMs.  That's the reason I didn't know about BOMs.